# get the filename from spring controller and assign in the html page on pageload

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have a file in my local folder c:/files/pdf/myData.pdf
Below is the code used to open PDF file on browser.

```
<object data="c:/files/pdf/myData.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <iframe src="c:/files/pdf/myData.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;">
         This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it 
     </iframe>
  </object>
```

I want to give the filename dynamically as the filename is not always myData.pdf.When ever user request new data,the old file gets deleted and new pdf file is created with new name, for this reason i cannot assign filename in data attribute of `<object..>` . I could not able to figure out **how to get the name of the file from the directory and assign to the `<object..>` tag either using angularjs or javascript.**

Below is my java code which gets the filename:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getFileName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getPDFName(){
        File folder = new File("C:\\files\\pdf");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        String fileName = null;
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                fileName = file.getName();
                // FileUtils.cleanDirectory(folder);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("fileName ::: " + fileName);
        return fileName;
    }
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you cannot access the filesystem in the way you are requesting, using JavaScript, as it would be considered a security vulnerability.

Comment: Can i hit the /getFileName controller through angularjs and assign it?